# ClassCastException android Integer to Long

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I was using an integer for the money factor in this little test app but I realized that long was more appropriate and I changed the code so that money is a long instead of an int and I changed SharedPreferences appropriately as well, however it does not work wheras it did when I used int. Thank you for the help!

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity { 

SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Intent intent;
TextView home_money_view;
long money; // this is the variable that is causing problems
int initial;

final long TEST = (long)-1;
int gold_pieces;
int gold_price = 50;
TimerTask timerTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    home_money_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_money_view)

    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();


    money = pref.getLong("temp_money",Long.MIN_VALUE); // get value
    if (money==Long.MIN_VALUE){
        money=0;
    }

    gold_pieces = pref.getInt("temp_gold",-1);
    if (gold_pieces==-1){
        gold_pieces=0;
    }

    initial = pref.getInt("initial",0);
    money+=initial;
    editor.putInt("initial",0);
    editor.commit();

    home_money_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_money_view);
    home_money_view.setText(money+"");
    editor.commit();
}

public void backToSplash(View view){
    intent = new Intent(Home.this,BusinessSelector.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void goToSecondView(View view){

    long temp_money = money;
    editor.putLong("temp_money",temp_money); // set value
    int temp_gold = gold_pieces;
    editor.putInt("temp_gold",temp_gold);
    editor.commit();
    intent = new Intent(Home.this,SecondView.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void goToOtherView(View view) {

    long temp_money = money;
    editor.putLong("temp_money",temp_money); // set value

    int temp_gold = gold_pieces;
    editor.putInt("temp_gold", temp_gold);
    editor.commit();
    intent = new Intent(Home.this, Next.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}


}
```

Logcat:

```
04-13 19:01:03.675 12896-12896/com.exampleryancocuzzo.ryan.markettycoon   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exampleryancocuzzo.ryan.markettycoon/com.exampleryancocuzzo.ryan.markettycoon.Home}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
                                                                                          at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getLong(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:228)
                                                                                          at com.exampleryancocuzzo.ryan.markettycoon.Home.onCreate(Home.java:56)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: On a side note, I will be able to respond to answers and comments in a couple hours, because I will be unavailable but I will be coming right back

Comment: Did you clear your apps  preferences after changing it from int to long? Your shared preferences may still have an int in them from when you were storing it as an int. This would cause the class cast exception since you are trying to access it as a long.

Comment: I added editor.clear and it worked

Comment: Just for future reference, you can clear preferences of an app on the device by going to app info > clear data. That can be useful if you don't want to have to edit your code to clear it.

Comment: Oh Thank you, that actually is helpful